# How do I make The BEST Haste Elixir?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I was wondering, I got a mid level haste elixir with a few hot-footed frogs and a monster part, but how do I get the TOP level haste effect?

Comment: Did you use 4 frogs and a monster part?

Comment: no i used 3 frogs and i think a bokoblin gut.

Comment: Try using 4 for a maximal effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For elixers, the magnitude of the effect is determined by the number of things used that give the boost, and duration is determined by the "quality" of the monster part you combine them with. Typically, the harder to get the monster part, the longer the duration of elixer is creates.

You need to combine 4 of the same boost in an elixer to get a +3 boost to a stat.

Answer (score -2):

4 Hot-Footed Frog and Lizalfos Horn. You may substitute 1 Rushroom for a frog. I think the key is using Lizalfos parts for haste. They are the fastest enemy.

Comment: Monster parts do not add to the strength of the buff, only the duration. Lizalfos tails are decent, but rarer ingredients (such as Lynel guts) are much better.